# Is there a fix for a fatal error caused by the WordPress REST API when adjusting media and menus?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

today somehow i was not able to upload or even see any of the media or change my menu. I was getting this error

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strlen(): Argument #1 ($str) must be of type string, array given in /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/.d055be9e.mo(65) : eval()'d code:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/.d055be9e.mo(65) : eval()'d code(4): ptcgyaj() #1 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/.d055be9e.mo(65): eval() #2 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(4): include('/home/ppj1j965k...') #3 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-settings.php(34): require('/home/ppj1j965k...') #4 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-config.php(109): require_once('/home/ppj1j965k...') #5 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/ppj1j965k...') #6 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/ppj1j965k...') #7 /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php(13): require_once('/home/ppj1j965k...') #8 {main} thrown in /home/ppj1j965kh7n/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/.d055be9e.mo(65) : eval()'d code on line 4

But when I tried to look for the corrupted file in the rest api folder in cpanel it was not there.
Please tell me how do i fix this?

Tried to upload image to wordpress media files were not showing also couldnt chamge the menu.